# Reloading of page does not route to correct nested route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This used to work well when I have only 1 level of routing but after having 2 levels it does not work.

I have a root router

```
{ path: '/', name: 'Index', component: Index, useAsDefault: true },
{ path: '/settings/...', name: 'Settings', component: Settings }
```

and in setting I have many more async routes.

```
AsyncRoute {aux: null, path: "./", name: "Overview", data: undefined, useAsDefault: undefined}
```

etc.

When I navigate via route-links it works but when I reload my page at say /settings/user/info it loads a blank page with ¸only stuff from root script but without anything in the router-outlet.

How do I fix this? Has it got something to do with the async routes having relative paths specified?

Comment: Can you create a full example (Plunker). Might be related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6428

Comment: How accurately can I replicate my issue since it's related to page reloading and not angula routing?

Comment: I don't understand your problem and I have no way to reproduce it. A full example would demonstrate what you try to accomplish. If it can't be reproduce in a Plunker I could easily create the project locally from the source to reproduce.

Comment: Sounds like your data is only being created as you traverse the application's views. And when you reload that data is not present and you get a blank view.

Comment: Are you  using the HashLocation Strategy?

Answer (score 1):

I had met the same issue but I resolved by using this code inside  of index.html.Its a bug with APP_BASE_HREF

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <!-- Set the base href -->
    <script>document.write('<base href="'+ document.location +'"/>');</script>
</head>
```